# Converting vertical datum from WGS84 to EGM96 in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, datum, srtm, vertical-transformation

I am comparing two different Digital Elevation Models

1. SRTM (Datum: EGM96)
2. Cartosat (Datum: WGS84)

How to convert WGS84 to EGM96 in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS? You can project rasters with vertical datums at Pro 2.1 and maybe Desktop 10.6.0.

Comment: @mkennedy we have ArcGIS 10.5.1

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273739/how-to-convert-vertical-datum-from-wgs84-to-egm96#comment436489_273786):

> Vertical transformations are available for vector data at [ArcGIS
>   Desktop] 10.5.1 and [ArcGIS] Pro 2.0. On-the-fly in Pro 2.1.

[FAQ: Are vertical datum transformations supported in ArcGIS?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009143) suggests they may have been available in ArcGIS Desktop slightly earlier:

> Vertical datum transformations are supported in ArcGIS version 10.4
>   and above. It is possible to apply a vertical datum transformation
>   using the Project tool.
>
> While it is possible to define the vertical coordinate system
>   information for z-coordinates of several data formats in ArcGIS 10.3
>   and previous releases, vertical datum transformations are not
>   supported in these releases.

For the latest ArcGIS Desktop help on this topic see [Vertical datums](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/projections/vertical-datums.htm).

Once we know the version of ArcGIS Desktop that you are using, and precisely what you have tried, we may be able to offer further assistance.

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned I am dealing with the DEM (raster files) of two different sources. I will try and update the answer if problem persist.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do a vertical datum transformation in ArcGIS.  Give vDatum a try. https://vdatum.noaa.gov/

Comment: That's old information. Vertical transformations are available for vector data at 10.5.1 and Pro 2.0. On-the-fly in Pro 2.1.

Comment: @mkennedy - Yes, but the original question is in regard to DEMs in ArcGIS Desktop.  My answer is correct.

Comment: And rasters in Pro 2.1.