# Vertical Datum transformation for raster using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, datum, vertical-transformation

I have a DEM raster file on WGS84 CRS and height referenced to ellipsoid on same datum. I want to convert that DEM to local CRS (horizontal & vertical) including the vertical datum transformation. I have one approach from which i can generate gridded points and extract the DEM values for those and then using Blue Marble Geographic Calculator I can transform those points after that just convert it back to DEM. I tried applying transformation but it is only for horizontal datum only.

Can we can transformation directly on raster for orthometric heights using ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: In theory yes but I have never gotten it to work:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396585/vertical-datum-conversion-in-arcgis-pro-not-recognizing-vertical-coordinate-syst  What local vertical datum are you trying to convert to?  Maybe vDatum will work for you. https://vdatum.noaa.gov/

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot share the area, but i have the local geoid model as .bgd file

Comment: Esri doesn't support a .bgd format so you'd first have to convert it to something we do support like NGS's geoid format.